# Two questions about footnote layout/spacing: How to get left-aligned non-hanging FNs with digit-adjusted space after FN number?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, footmisc

(update) I played around with settings some more, which changes my question (old question left unchanged below). The new question is:

I currently use

```
\usepackage[ragged]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{7pt}
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\hskip3pt}

\addtolength{\footnotesep}{4pt} 
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{3pt}
```

Which produces a footnote layout I like (non-hanging footnote text, with space between footnote marker and footnote text). Except for one problem:
The footnote number is not *left aligned* for digits below 10.

Is there a way to make the number align left, keep a **fixed** space between the number and the text, and have the text adjust accordingly to the right (which I think should work since I'm using option 'ragged' in footmisc)

Sorry for the back-and-forth in my question.

---

---

Two (possibly related) questions about footnote spacing and layout. The code generating the examples is at the end of the question.

First one: is the following a side effect of some of settings, or why does it seem that the space between the footnote number and the text body (in the footnote itself) doesn't take into account the number of digits?

See the following two examples, where space is greater for the single digit footnote than the double digit one:

[image: 1a]

[image: 1b]

Any way to make the space between number and footnote text adjust with the digits of the footnote number?

---

Second question: I currently use footmisc with option 'hang', and set length of 'footnotemargin' to produce some distance between the number and the footnote text. This is the current layout, for a 2 line footnote:

[image: 2]

My question is, is there any way, using a combination of footmisc options and other settings/command redefinitions to produce a footnote layout that looks as follows:

```
Some text here. <-- Left edge of text body
-----------     <-- footnote divider
1  Some text  <-- 1st line of footnote. footnote number left aligned, followed by small space, followed by footnote text.
more text.  <-- 2nd line of footnote, text left aligned
```

In other words: footnote numbers are fully left-aligned, followed by a small space, followed by the text, but the second line of a footnote does *not* hang? I tried unsucessfully to get this to work with a combination of footmisc options, but no idea how or if it works.

---

Relevant footnote settings/code. If this isn't informative enough, I can turn the fragement into a full MWE.

```
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10pt}

\addtolength{\footnotesep}{3pt}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{3pt}
```

The example images are the results of using

```
\footnotemark{}
\footnotetext{}
```

But regular

```
\footnote{}
```

seems to behave the same.

Comment: Did you mean "Hart's Rule" style for footnotes which is a requirement of Oxford University Press"? please excuse me if not so...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that rule :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ragged]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\hskip12pt}% 

\addtolength{\footnotesep}{4pt} 
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{3pt}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
  \footnotemark%
  {\def\thefootnote{\makebox[0pt][l]{\svthefootnote}}\footnotetext{#1}}%
}
\textheight=3in% REMOVE THIS FROM ACTUAL DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
Test\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and%
\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and\footnote{text} and%
\footnote{text}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Warning, you may need/wish to change the skip value of `\footnotelayout`, depending on how many footnotes appear on a page.

Comment: Maybe because I changed the page geometry, using your code as means the footnotes numbers are outside the margins, to the left.
If I change \footnotemargin from 0pt, the footnote is shifted to the right, but then, the alignment is lost. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @BertZangle Yes.  The shift of the text can be accomplished by changing the `\hskip` within `\footnotelayout`, whereas the shift of the digits is accomplished with a change in the `\makebox` width within the redefined `\thefootnote` (negative will shift to the right).

Comment: Can't really get the digit shift to work, as in:
... {\def\thefootnote{\makebox[0pt][l]{\svthefootnote}} ...
and ... {\def\thefootnote{\makebox[-20pt][l]{\svthefootnote}} ... produce the same output.
Marking as 'answered' however, since the last bit is so minimal, it doesn't really matter. Thanks!

Comment: @BertZangle Thanks.  Maybe the `\documentclass` has something to do with it.  I presume, using just my MWE, that you can get the left/right shift by changing the `\makebox` size?

Comment: I think I found the culprit. I can get your MWE to work if using \foonote{}, but not if I use \footnotemarker{} ... \footnotetext{}, which is how I usually add all of my footnotes (makes it easier to read for myself, imo). Any way you can make sense of that?

Comment: @BertZangle I think so, though I have no time now.  Whereas as I redefined `\footnote`, you would need to redefine just `\footnotetext` to do the `\def`.  Note also I put it in a group, so that the change was not made permanent, lest it screw up `\footnotemark`.